# Printing out the OPCODES to which a Python Re is compiled?

Tags: python, regex, compilation

Python's `re` module allows for some compilation of a given regex pattern.

For example,

```
import re
c = re.compile('(?<=abc)def')
```

How can I print out the code the expression is compiled to? Any links to some documentation about the implementation details would also be helpful

The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/re/_compiler.py) suggests that this compilation is done to some kind of internal VM (like [PikeVM](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html)). The opcodes of this VM can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/re/_constants.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to supply `re.DEBUG` to the `flags=`:

```py
import re

re.compile("(?<=abc)def", flags=re.DEBUG)
```

Prints:

```
ASSERT -1
  LITERAL 97
  LITERAL 98
  LITERAL 99
LITERAL 100
LITERAL 101
LITERAL 102

 0. INFO 4 0b0 3 3 (to 5)
 5: ASSERT 9 3 (to 15)
 8.   LITERAL 0x61 ('a')
10.   LITERAL 0x62 ('b')
12.   LITERAL 0x63 ('c')
14.   SUCCESS
15: LITERAL 0x64 ('d')
17. LITERAL 0x65 ('e')
19. LITERAL 0x66 ('f')
21. SUCCESS
```

Comment: Is there some documentation about these OPCODES? and what the top and the bottom part of this display means?

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay I'm not aware of any documentation (best documentation is the code after all). What I found is this module: https://github.com/JelleZijlstra/regdis But I'm not sure how it works.